# Using defineModel macro does not trigger update of state in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, store

Please find at the below link a minimal example of the type of thing I am trying to achieve in Vue.

[Vue SFC Playground link](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqVU8Fu2zAM/RVBl6RA5mDozXMCbEU3bNjaYd1RF8+mE2Wy7ElymsHwv4+UbMUrghY9BJHER/Lx8bnn79s2OXbAU57ZwsjWMQuua7dCy7ptjGM3e6lKVpmmZotk7W+UsIiAnu3A3eU1rCiVDmyI+AfXGFi8m4GLpm47B+WECbWELhptHdOUvomgZS80o/opW16xzXZqtbxaUQD7YUDDI735+Mggvgk94C9bh9lwKrw4qFuVO8AbY9n+7daTZMdcdZCyPs6DHYchWyPAA4MQxzd1U4JKieg3Om0Ep7PgbI24bD2rzlfcWZyrkrvkYBuNIvt5BKf5pAJz3zqJcwuOfSlCsVyp5vGLf3OmAz+oz9lD8fvC+8Ge6E3w7wYsmCNSiTGXGxwmhG8f7uCE5xjEQTqF6GeCP8A2qiOOAfah0yXSnuE8289+uVLvftrbkwNtp6GIKCEHjxccl33zzOhnutfJtc/D/aGK0XUXbBp845eCximhkjosZrmIO1qsWO/+trjd+18HKNyKGfjTSQNloPiSR2yb6+1HaSaDSo3uTBmmUIBl/j5ZAw3h/5OKEshIgs/KfM1fV0UhPhaZ2Qtl8b5FZ6EqQYVg5E0QlHqM2kYmfodSqXGBU216/oRFcRsoOIouNJz891p1uqA9zb4JX9Gg+kaHhon3v76Y9vR7DNnntInsfxxH8FnA0W1nuhMiijN5ZfgHbPakPw==)

In my real application, I have several pieces of data maintained in my store which require the same format of input. Therefore, I want to create a general input form which will receive the values from the parent component, and will create a 2-way binding between them, updating the store in the main component. This setup means I cannot simply update the store in the child component, since I don't know at the input component's level which of the store's values the input component is managing.

However, when I set things up as in the example provided, the store is never updated when the values in the input changes. I cannot figure out why this is.

It seems this is something to do with Vue detecting changes in the object. If I remove the `v-model` directives in the child, and replace them with `:value` and `@input`, then use handlers which fully overwrite the `model.value` object, *then* reactivity is restored. See the below link for a working example. I'm just not sure my understanding is 100% solid, and if there's a way to make it work with the simpler v-model.

[Vue SFC Playground link w/ working example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make store reactive too, so in Your `Store.js` :

```
import { reactive} from 'vue'
const Store = reactive({
  name: {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates"
  }
})
...
```

Comment: So yes, that works. However, that does not call the `set()` function from the parent component, rather it is updating the store object directly since that is what is returned by the `get()` function. If I change the store to return a copy of the `name` value from `getName`, it is no longer reactive, which circumvents the use of getters and setters.

Comment: @Catradora the source should be reactive for `getName()` to be called when the store changes. so the answer is correct. There's no other way to provide reactivity

Comment: You are correct, however if you change `getName` to return `{...Store.name}`, the reactivity is removed. `Store` needs to be reactive in all cases, yes, but simply adding `reactive` to the store does not ensure reactivity when the direct store object is not being acted upon, as would be the case when ensuring store mutations happen only through defined store mutation functions.

Comment: `if you change getName to return {...Store.name}` - then don't do that?